# I am trying to send Datagram Packages over UDP using Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to send data over a UDP network using Datagram packet & Socket I am unable to send data using Asynctask class I tried the code given on Boxeeremote but it isn't working .
Can anybody Help me In how to use the Boxxeeremote in Android programming?
& How to acheive the same using Asynctask

Comment: yes show ur code i have done several socket projects

Comment: The code is given on  https://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP         But it isn't working on Android

Comment: How do you know it is not working?  Is your intended recipient even on a routable network? And remember there is no guarantee with UDP.

Comment: I am trying this on Wlan and I know the IP of subnet & same thing works if I do simply in JAVA as Unicast

Comment: I just want to acheive the same in Android using  Asynctask i.e. 1.Show that message is broadcasting on preExecute 2.Broad cast message in do in Background 3.Display th IP of participants Host on Post Execute